# Can we use Concate layer for two different size of input images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am implement multiple scale input for my network

```
input1(WxH)    -->Network----| 
                             |-->SoftmaxWithLoss
input2(W/2xH/2)-->Network----|
                             ^
label(WxH)-------------------|
```

The scheme is very simple, just use same network architecture but different image scale. Can I use `Concate` layer for that task? Specially, the layer prototxt will be

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "input1"
  top: "input2"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN 
  }
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "./list2.txt"
    batch_size: 2
  }
}

layer {
  name: "concat"
  type: "Concat" 
  bottom: "input1"
  bottom: "input2"
  top: "data"
}
```

Comment: what do you expect the output `shape` of  the `data` "top" would be?

Comment: My expect output shape will be `WxH`, but the network must be processed with two input `WxH` and `W/2xH/2` individually. And the final output will be fuse together

Comment: so you cannot `concat` `input1` and `input2` together as they have different `shape`s.

Comment: Thanks. So I need make two parallel networks, Is it right?

Comment: you can share weights between the two copies.. you can skip a pooling layer for the downscale input and concat high-res pooled features with low-res un-pooled features half way...

Comment: Can you make an example for clarifying it? Sorry I am not truly understand it